# Как правильно вызывать методы из других методов в рамках одного API Django REST?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

Как правильно вызвать метод из другого метода в рамках одного API? Если вызываю через self, выдает ошибку.

```
class SomeAPI(mixins.UpdateModelMixin, generics.ListCreateAPIView):
     permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]

     def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         data = request.data 
         ...
         self.somefunc(p1,p2,p3,p4) # здесь должен быть вызван метод sumefunc()
         return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)  

     def somefunc(p1,p2,p3,p4):
         ...
```

ошибка: `Exception Value: somefunc() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given`

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста что за ошибка

Comment: @ivanK. обновил вопрос

Comment: Я уже ответил_)Проверьте пожалуйста, ошибка уйдет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте поменять *def somefunc(p1,p2,p3,p4)* на *def somefunc(**self**,p1,p2,p3,p4):*

**UDP**

Для всех методов класса, первый аргумент должен быть *self*